# Need an Expression to Split a DateRange column into 3 bins

Tags: spotfire

I want to represent count of ID's wrt to Daterange column. I tried to split it into bins but there was option to split into no of parts and not as 3 differnt date values.I want to split the Date Range column into 3 parts so that i  can represent the data in a bar chart as Current,Pat and Future data. Each of the 3 bins are represented as:

1.Current - Count of ID for Current month[Dec 2016]. The data for current month should be dunamically calculated since if the next month comes the data should point to that by the dynalic calculation

2.Past - Count of ID for Data less than current month[Data < Dec 2016]. I need to be able to dynamically change the no of months using custom expression so that user can chnage th e no of months it goes back to. Need the expression in such a way that it can be set by a custom expression ,if not the nos can be changed at the expression

3.Future - Count of ID for Data greater than current month[Data  Dec 2016]. I need to be able to dynamically change the no of months using custom expression so that user can chnage th e no of months in the future. There will be future dates available since it is a data for manintenance done in the future time.

This 3 data needs to be as a custom/binned column so that the data is represented as shown in the attached picture.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create a calculated column...

```
case 
    when DatePart('month',[DateColumn]) = DatePart('month',DateTimeNow())  and DatePart('year',[DateColumn]) = DatePart('year',DateTimeNow()) then "Current"
    when [DateColumn] < DateTimeNow() and [DateColumn] >= DateAdd('month',${NumOfMonthsBack} * (-1),[DateColumn]) then "Past"
    when [DateColumn] > DateTimeNow() and [DateColumn] <= DateAdd('month',${NumOfMonthsAhead},[DateColumn]) then "Future"
end as [MonthRange]
```

Comment: `case 
     when DatePart('month',[Date Range]) = DatePart('month',DateTimeNow())  and DatePart('year',[Date Range]) = DatePart('year',DateTimeNow()) then "Current"
     when [Date Range] < DateTimeNow() then "Past"
     when [Date Range] > DateTimeNow() then "Future"
end as [MonthRange]`
Will the above logic suffice for scenario without month nos, my doubt is if '[Date Range] < DateTimeNow()' then wont it consider same month lesser date as past?

Comment: No you'll have to check a few things. First if the month is before the current one if it's in the same year. If it isn't in the same year then just check if the year is before the current year. This would be referred for future dates. I.e 1/14/2017 is in the future but the month number isn't ahead of this month, hence the year check